# Pages don't get blocked with Squid over HTTPS

Tags: regular-expression, proxy, web, squid, https

I have set up Squid to block pages on my own system (i.e not on a network), and I'm trying to get SSL to work with page blocking. To this end, I've set up ssl-bump and installed the certificate to my browser.

I want to block `*.reddit.com/*` (on both HTTPS and HTTP), but I want to allow the child URL `*.reddit.com/r/LearnJapanese` only (on both HTTP and HTTPS)

Here is part of my squid.conf file:

```
acl bad_domain url_regex "/usr/local/squid/etc/block.acl"
acl good_domain url_regex "/usr/local/squid/etc/allow.acl"

http_access deny bad_domain !good_domain
http_access allow good_domain

http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost

http_access deny all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128 ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=10MB cert=/usr/local/squid/etc/squid.pem

ssl_bump allow all

sslproxy_cert_error allow all
sslproxy_flags DONT_VERIFY_PEER
```

Contents of block.acl:

```
^http(s)?://(.+)?reddit\.com(.+)?$
```

Contents of allow.acl:

```
^http(s)?://(.+)?reddit\.com/r/LearnJapanese(.+)?$
```

It works fine of HTTP (i.e reddit.com/r/LearnJapanese can be accessed, but the rest of Reddit cannot), but I don't have the same luck with HTTPS.

When I access Reddit over HTTPS, the pages are not blocked at all, but they should be (except for reddit.com/r/LearnJapanese of course).

How can I block access to all of Reddit (aside from *.reddit.com/r/LearnJapanese/*) over both HTTP and HTTPS? Thank you.

Comment: Try this regex `^http[s]?:\/\/(w{3}\.| \.)reddit\.com\/r\/LearnJapanese(\/)?$` Check https://regex101.com/r/xS1wF7/2 ....if any particular error shows up regarding regex character escaping/usage let me know..

Comment: @heemayl, do you know if this egrep-compatible? Squid (as far as I read somewhere) will only accept egrep-style regexes, which is why I kept it simple. I think my regex works (because it works for HTTP), the question is why nothing works when I access reddit over HTTPS. I'll try your regex.

Comment: I see..my regex is `egrep` compatible but your problem seems different, its not about regex..i heard people have very hard times blocking `https` though `squid`..search for relevant threads..also you can try [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/) to search for SysAdmins solutions regarding this..

Comment: This is a pretty good Ads blacklist --> [http://www.squidblacklist.org/downloads/squidblacklists/squid-ads.tar.gz](http://www.squidblacklist.org/downloads/squidblacklists/squid-ads.tar.gz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem by writing `ssl_bump server-first all` and removing `ssl_bump allow all`. I'm not sure if it contributed to fixing the problem, but I also put these lines into my terminal:

```
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p TCP -s 127.0.0.1 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p TCP -s 127.0.0.1 --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
```

Although this does not produce the "Access Denied" message when I try to navigate to blacklisted pages with HTTPS, it does give me "Proxy server is refusing connections" when I configured Firefox to use the Squid proxy for all protocols (i.e HTTP and HTTPS) and I added the root certificate I generated earlier (`/usr/local/squid/etc/squid.pem`).

Answer (score 3):

Due to the fact that SSL is end-to-end encryption, a proxy such as Squid normally knows much less about an HTTPS request than it does on HTTP (http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/HTTPS#CONNECT_tunnel):

> [Many] common parts of the request URL do not exist in a CONNECT request:
>
> - the URL scheme or protocol (e.g., http://, https://, ftp://, voip://, itunes://, or telnet://),
> - the URL path (e.g., /index.html or /secure/images/),
> - and query string (e.g. ?a=b&c=d)

To know more than this about an HTTPS request, Squid would have to perform what is basically a man-in-the-middle attack on its clients. [The Squid documentation](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/HTTPS#Bumping_CONNECT_tunnels) explains how to do so, but note that this comes with a few issues regarding privacy (your users should trust you with their normally-encrypted information, and web browsers may warn about the attack).

Comment: I noticed after posting that you are already using `ssl_bump`. Then I'm not sure what's wrong; can you for sure whether your clients are seeing the Squid-provided certificate?

Comment: dhag: I've installed the certificate on both of my browsers (Chrome and Firefox) and when I visit http://reddit.com, the CA is the correct one (i.e the one provided by my root certificate I intalled in my browsers). I am using ssl-bump because only I am using Squid, there are no other users, so I'm only violating my own privacy. Is there anything other than `ssl-bump` I need to set up?

Comment: OK, then I really don't know what's wrong. Sorry for wasting your time :(. As a last stab, perhaps move the `ssl_bump` directive to be before the URL-based ACLs (I don't know whether that makes a difference, but we want to do the MITM before we can apply an URL regexp)?

Comment: I have news. I changed my proxy configuration (I switched the configuration from system-wide to Firefox-only) and there is *some* filtering, but not how it should be. If I navigate to https://reddit.com/r/x (which works), then click onto https://reddit.com/r/y, I get an Access Denied message that says "Access denied to https://reddit.com/r/x". That is, the message is too late and I can access any page simply be refreshing it. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: dhag: I tried moving the ssl-bump directives before the ACLs, but nothing changed. Thanks for your suggestion though